# Access to images in the public directory with Symfony 4

Tags: image, symfony, symfony4, assets, public-html

In two Symfony 4 instances, I get different results with the same code.
In a twig template, I have the line

```
<img src="{{  asset('images/DM_logo.jpg')}}"/>
```

In the online server, all works well: i get the image and the generated URL is /images/DM_logo.jpg for the absolute URL http://mysite.mydomain.com/images/DM_logo.jpg

But, locally, with the access to http://localhost/mysite/, the generated url is /mysite/images/DM_logo.jpg for the absolute url http://localhost/mysite/images/DM_logo.jpg which generate a NotFoundHttpException.

If i change the template to

```
<img src="{{  asset('public/images/DM_logo.jpg')}}"/>
```

it works locally but not online...

I doesn't find how to use the same code online and locally. Advices?

Comment: What URL do you use to access your site when developing? `localhost`, or `localhost/public`?

Comment: It seems to be a server web configuration error. What do you use in the local environment?

Answer (score 0):

configure this

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: 'example.org'
    router.request_context.base_url: 'my/path'
    asset.request_context.base_path: '%router.request_context.base_url%'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#routing-generating-urls